# Turtle code is executed, but does not draw in canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, turtle-graphics

I am currently working on a final for a simple Python course, however I have seemed to encounter something rather strange. The goal was to create a menu with error-exception checking and allow the user to initiate predefined functions. Everything works great **EXCEPT** for the `drawKochFractal` function.

It seems to compile and run completely fine, and I know the logic and math are correct. I have even added print statements to check where it is at in the console, and it is **definitely** running. But nothing is ever drawn or shows up on the canvas window! Have I overlooked something, or is it possibly my own python environment? Thank you!

```
elif select == 3:
            #Koch Function:
            """
            File: koch.py
            Project 7.3

            This program displays a Koch snowflake using
            the user's input level.
            """
            def drawKochFractal(width, height, size, level):
                """Draws a Koch fractal of the given level and size."""
                t.screen.colormode(255)
                t.pencolor(random.randint(1, 255),
                random.randint(1, 255),
                random.randint(1, 255))
                t.up()
                t.goto(-width // 3, height // 4)
                t.down()
                print("I am the begin")
                drawFractalLine(t, size, 0, level);
                print("I am here")
                drawFractalLine(t, size, -120, level)
                drawFractalLine(t, size, 120, level)

            def drawFractalLine(t, distance, theta, level):
                """Either draws a single line in a given direction
                or four fractal lines in new directions."""
                if (level == 0):
                    drawPolarLine(t, distance, theta)
                else:
                    drawFractalLine(t, distance // 3, theta, level - 1)
                    drawFractalLine(t, distance // 3, theta + 60, level - 1)
                    drawFractalLine(t, distance // 3, theta - 60, level - 1)
                    drawFractalLine(t, distance // 3, theta, level - 1)
                    print("I am here too!")

            def drawPolarLine(t, distance, theta):
                """Moves the given distance in the given direction."""
                t.setheading(theta)
                print("im turning!")
                t.forward(distance)

            width = input("Enter the width: ")
            height = input("Enter the height: ")
            size = input("Enter the size value: ")
            level = input("Enter the level (0 - 10): ")
            t = Turtle()
            t.hideturtle()
            t.screen.clear()
            #Let's make sure these variables are calculatable!
            try:
                width = int(width)
                height = int(height)
                size = int(size)
                level = int(level)
            except:
                print("####Invalid Response####")
                #If parameters do not work, send back to home menu
                main()
            #If level is not in correct range, send back to home menu with error response:
            if level > 10 or level < 0:
                print("####Level must be between 0 and 10####")
                main()
            #create drawKochFractal with user parameters, then take back to home menu:
            drawKochFractal(width, height, size, level)
            print("####Koch Fractal Complete! Taking you back to the main menu...####")
            main()
```

Comment: your code starts with an `elif` which is wrong. An `elif` clause needs to have an `if` previously

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with `turtle` but perhaps you need to indicate that you are done drawing with a call to `turtle.done()` or `turtle.tracer()`?

Comment: @GWW that is not how it works. But good idea!

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki What I posted is just the selection of the rest of the code, I didn't think people would want to scroll through the entire main.py! If i should post the rest of it, let me know!

Comment: `elif` only runs if the previous `elif` statements and the first `if` statement doesn’t run. Are you sure that the `elif` statement is running?

Comment: @EthanK it is, the print statements appear in the console and the turtle canvas window even pops up, but nothing is drawn.

Comment: @KontraBear oh... Try to replace those places with `t.down()` I really don’t know, that is weird. Does the turtle appear?

Comment: @EthanK It is most certainly strange, I tried your recommendations but no change. I have only gotten it to draw once, but only with very specific parameters and even then it only drew half of the snowflake (width,height,size = 100, level = 3). I will recheck the logic i suppose.

Comment: @KontraBear it must be the logic, so do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
t = Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.screen.clear()
```

The screen's `clear()` method damages existing user turtles and recreates the default one.  I suggest you try:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# ...

screen = Screen()
screen.clear()
t = Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
```

That is, create your turtle after the screen has been cleared and don't use your turtle to access the screen `clear()` method, use an independent pointer to the singular screen instance.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thank you very much!

Comment: @KontraBear, what I would suggest is that you use the *same* turtle for all your drawing, rather than create new ones, and then ask that turtle to `clear()` or `reset()` itself when needed which is a cleaner (saner) operation.